# Two current requirements sharing one battery and connected logically

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, led, circuit-design

I'm trying to build a project but my knowledge in circuit design is more than limited (or is it less than limited? Anyway, the lower of the two).

My project requires the use of a microcontroller to control some LEDs based on sensors. My problem originates from the fact that the microcontroller can only supply 40 mAh via its pins while the LEDs consume much more.

I've googled and landed on the use of a MOSFET (I'm not sure I quite understand yet what they are) like you would use a relay.

My project will be battery powered and hopefully only one battery will be needed, but from the bit of googling I've done it seems like MOSFETs connect between two entirely different circuits which do not share a power source.

I've done my best in designing a circuit, but I'm far from being confident in it working, so I would highly appreciate if you could help me by reviewing it.

The LEDs' forward current is 350 mA and the forward voltage is 2.2 V. The battery is 3.7 V.

I've also calculated that each LED needs a 4.28 Ω resistor which seems wrong for some reason.

[image]

p.s. I'll more than understand if this doesn't belong in this forum, if you have a better suited place for me to ask this please tell me.

Comment: Each LED needs 350 mA? Are they being controlled individually or as a unit? That is a pretty large current for an LED, I know some I like to use are more around 5-25 mA and I do use resistors around 330-700 ohms. That’s probably why your low series resistor value makes sense. This site might be a good reference for you: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html

Comment: @jakob they are supposedly quite powerful leds I (at typical 45 Luminous Flux) have yet to try them but I sure hope they are powerful as this circuit is actually supposed to be a bike light, I have also bought them from amazon since there isn't any other normally priced stores here so I imagine they aren't the most efficient

Comment: Ahh ok that explains the current usage. The LEDs I’ve used were surface mount meant for status indicators or something.

Answer (score 2):

When using MOSFETs, switching the low-side is usually preferred. Unless your load is referenced to ground, then you need to switch the high-side.

You need to pick a MOSFET that will turn on completely with the signal from your MCU. Look for the words "logic-level" in the description. But, you still need to look at the V-I plot for various gate voltages. At your expected current (for all 3 LEDs), you want the voltage drop to be low. You want to be on the part of the curve on the left where the lines are straight. Find your total current on the left then find the voltage drop where the gate curve intersects. You want the gate voltage to be very low. For your load and this MOSFET you may be off the curve to the left, which is good.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHgj1V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, I'll definitely will look into these terms later on, but I still wonder about whether its ok for the leds and the microcontroller to share the same battery.

Comment: Yes, they can share the same battery assuming that the high-current LEDs don't cause the  voltage to dip too much. Use thick wires. Make sure that your battery can supply this much current without dipping too much.

Comment: IRL640A is a good choice for the MOSFET.